# Saving data sets with different names in r

Tags: r, names

I want to save variables with different names. I made simplified form of my code.

```
a <- runif(10, 1, 10)
for (i in 1:10)
{
 b = a[i]
}
```

I want to save variables with names such as b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, ... b_10.

How can I change the variable names.

I think this might be simple, but...do not know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't do that (really there is no reason to do that!). Put them into a `list`.

Comment: Instead of b_1 what is wrong with a[1]? @Roland For their example I don't even think a list is necessary.

Comment: @Dason Sure, but it's a simplified example.

Comment: @Roland Most likely but it might not be.  Still - either using direct indexing or using a list is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Yes, sorry to make this simple example. I think this example is a little bit stupid but straightforward. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I am just curious about how to assign different names when I want to save several datasets in for loop.